# Custom Login in Shortcode got error

Tags: shortcode, login

I am creating a shortcode that having a login form but it seems I got error when I try to login. this is my code.

```
function postCustomWPLogin($username, $password){
$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = $username;
$creds['user_password'] = $password;
$creds['remember'] = true;
$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
if ( is_wp_error($user) ){
    echo $user->get_error_message();    
}else{
    $userID = $user->ID;

    wp_set_current_user( $userID, $user_login );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $userID, true, false );
    do_action( 'wp_login', $user_login );
  }

}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'postCustomWPLogin' );

function MyForm() {

if($_POST['srmsform_type'] == 'userLogin'){
    postCustomWPLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
}
$form_ret = '';
$form_ret .= '<p>Existing users, Please Login to enroll.<br> If you are registering for the first time, Please click "Register" below.</p>';
$form_ret .= "<form id='srmsform_userlogin' action='".str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])."' method='post'>";
$form_ret .= '<input type="hidden" name="srmsform_type" value="userLogin">';                                                                                                
$form_ret .= "<label>User Name</br></label><input type='text' name='username' value='' id='username'></br>";
$form_ret .= "<br><label>Password</br></label><input type='password' name='password' value='' id='password'></br>";
$form_ret .= '<input type="hidden" name="instanceID" value="Some Values">';
$form_ret .= '<input type="hidden" name="courseType" value="Some Values">';
$form_ret .= "<br><input type='submit' id='enrolnow' class='course-button' value='Login'><br>";     
$form_ret .= "</form>";
return $form_ret;
}

add_shortcode( 'My_form', 'MyForm' );
```

When I tried to login in my login form in my shortcode.. I got this error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/tidecoma/public_html/development/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/header.php:13) in /home/tidecoma/public_html/development/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 918

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/tidecoma/public_html/development/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/header.php:13) in /home/tidecoma/public_html/development/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 919

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/tidecoma/public_html/development/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/header.php:13) in /home/tidecoma/public_html/development/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 920

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/tidecoma/public_html/development/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/header.php:13) in /home/tidecoma/public_html/development/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 918

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/tidecoma/public_html/development/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/header.php:13) in /home/tidecoma/public_html/development/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 919

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/tidecoma/public_html/development/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/header.php:13) in /home/tidecoma/public_html/development/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 920
```

does anyone have an idea about my case and how to deal with it? thanks in advance

Comment: `postCustomWPLogin` function is for logging in, right? Why are you hooking it to `after_setup_theme`?

Comment: thanks for the respone Nilambar, yes that is for logging in.. I have read it on this link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon so I tried to follow it but it didn't work for me...